# How to find the norm 2 of a complex function $f(z) = a - bz - c|z{|^2}z$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

Let a function:

$f(z) = a - bz - c|z{|^2}z$

where, $a,b,c,z \in C$ and $|.|$ represent the norm 2 operation.

How to find norm 2 of $f(z)$ that is $|f(z)|=?$

(The reason I am asking because I know that $|z|=\sqrt{zz^*}$.
How should I use that for the case of $|f(z)|$?